# Calling web service using Rest template - Dynamic JSON output

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, resttemplate

I am using Rest template in Spring to call web service and parse through the JSON which it outputs. But I am currently domain classes based on the structure of the JSON.

If in case, the structure of JSON changes, I might have to manually create classes based on new structure.

Do we have any way of generating these classes dynamically?

Comment: Based on what for the generation dynamically? i don't thing so that you can do that, if the web service give you the wadl or wsdl or you make your own, is possible to do the generation, but if not, simple get the answer and put it in the object wrapper (or something like that) that he will get the object and make the auto conversion to json, the only problem will be that you not have control of the name of variables.

Comment: For more help you can see http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes